# Wordpress database widget sidebar search: how to connect the html form, php search-engine and the database on the server

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, ftp

I'm new on WordPress, but I have some experience in developing php and mysql applications. At the moment I am working on a sidebar database search in a website that has been built by using wordpress and has been hosted on dreamhost. First I wrote the search engine in a localhost and now it functions as I expect. Now I want to embed the code to the wordpress website but I do not understand how exactly I have to do that. I have done a lot of search but I could not find what exactly would work for my case.
So far I could add the html frontend code to a sidebar widget text. It's a typical search that contains a form with several textboxes and a search button and calls a php file in its action(inside form tag).
I also managed to upload the php file to the dreamhost by using FTP client(FileZilla) in a directory (the FTP link (directory) that is provided in 'Manage Domains' section in dreamhodt panel ) and I'am not sure if it is related to the directory that wordpress is installed on (actually I cannot find the directory that wordpress is on it since it was not created by me and the person who has created it doesn't know where it is too).
Besides, I migrated my database form the localhost to the dreamhost server. So now I have the database created and populated on dreamhost.
The main problem is that I still don't know how to connect the wordpress sidebar search UI and the php file (search engine) and the database that are installed on the same server but seemingly different directories. 
I don't know if I was supposed to upload the back-end php database search-engine (that is a long code) directly to wordpress (I also searched a lot for this but I could not find an appropriate answer) and in that case where and how exactly on wordpress I have to upload it and how I have to connect the front-end html search and back-end php search-engine and the database back on the server. Additionally I don't know the edits I have to do on the wp-config.php .

I did not put any code here because I think what I tried to explain shows my problem and actually the problem is not about the code but it is about how to connect them on the server to have them functional. But still if someone needs the code or part of it to have a better idea I wouldn't hesitate to provide the code if she/he asks.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a project like this, you should be building it as a plugin. Unless you can't avoid it, you don't want to go changing core files, as this can completely break your ability to upgrade Wordpress.

There are lots of tutorials on the internet, but I'd start with [the Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) to at least familiarize yourself with the terms and concepts of how a plugin works before delving deeper.

For creating the widgets, take a look at the [Widgets API documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API).

[This Book from Packt](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/wordpress-3-plugin-development-essentials) helped me grok the development process when I was getting started. It also has an example inside of pretty much exactly what you want to achieve.

To develop this, you'll want to mirror your Wordpress install onto your localhost, so you don't break the live site. The [XCloner plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/xcloner-backup-and-restore/) makes this pretty easy, just don't leave it active on your live site any longer than you absolutely need to since it can be a vector for attackers.

Comment: Thanks very much for this kind and comprehensive answer. I hope it does not take a lot of time to learn and implement the things that you have mentioned since my deadline is close.

Comment: Can you please tell me if I need to install my database again on wordpress?

Comment: I can't. I don't have enough information about what you're doing to make a guess.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question: I solved my problem by using cpilko's answer and advise but still I had to search and read a lot to find a way for integrating my app to a wordpress website and many of the document that I found didn't give me enough perspective for how to create a plugin on top of wordpress that takes data through a form in a page sidebar and based on the data the select query would be constructed in a backend php file and the reasult of the query would be displayed in an html table in a new page.
In addition to (http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin),
this link (http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-wordpress-plugin-from-scratch--net-2668) has helped me a lot to find out how exactly I have to connect my code and wordpress. About the data base connection  I just decided to add my table to wordpress database itself so I wouldn't be forced to create another connection to another database.